# Creating UILabel programmatically with dynamic size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to create `UILabel` programmatically, but height and width should be set dynamically depending on the content. I don't want to create initial `CGRect` with some width and height, which cause design issues in my case.

What I tried to do is:

```
        self.freeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameView.layer.frame.size.width - 50, -8, 120, 25)];
        self.freeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        [self.freeLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.91 green:0.18 blue:0.42 alpha:1.0]];
        self.freeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        self.freeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [self addSubview:self.freeLabel];
        [self sizeToFit];
```

but this way I cannot add the `UILabel` to my view.

Comment: Initial `frame` could be `zero`. Why do you care about that?

Comment: add constraints to your label ...

Comment: how `freeLabel` is defined? Most important... also u want to resize based on text size... right?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add below codes so that `self.freeLabel` with take new height.

```
[self.freeLabel sizeToFit];

self.freeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(frameView.layer.frame.size.width - 50, -8, 120, self.freeLabel.frame.size.height)];

self.frame = // update size based on the height of the label.
```

But I have some points which I feel are wrong.

Why x position of `self.freeLabel` is defined as `frameView.layer.frame.size.width - 50` but width of label as `120`. For sure this label will go out of your view. So `frameView.layer.frame.size.width - 50` should be `frameView.layer.frame.size.width - 120`